# Error Call to undefined function storage_patch() cuando ejecuto un seeder en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, mariadb, seeders

Estoy intentando ejecutar un seeder pero me sale el error: `Call to undefined function storage_patch()` No he podido dar con el.

tengo una tabla en migracion llamada user con los sgts campos:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {   

        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            //llave foranea rol por defecto con  default estudiante
            $table->unsignedInteger('role_id')->default(\App\Role::STUDENT);
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('slug');
            //puede ser nulo el campo
            $table->string('picture')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');


            //cashier columns
            $table->string('stripe_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('card_brand')->nullable();
            $table->string('card_last_four')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('trial_ends_at')->nullable();

            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
        });

    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');

    }
}
```

La factoria para los users las tengo asi:

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    //definicion de variables
    $name=$faker->name;
    $last_name=$faker->lastName;
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'role_id'=>\App\Role::all()->random()->id,
        'last_name'=>$last_name,
        'slug'=>str_slug($name." ".$last_name,'-'),
        'picture'=>\Faker\Provider\Image::image(storage_patch().'/app/public/users',200,200,'people',false),
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password' => '$2y$10$TKh8H1.PfQx37YgCzwiKb.KjNyWgaHb9cbcoQgdIVFlYg7B77UdFm', // secret
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ];
});
```

Cuando me genera el error me señala el campo **picture** del archivo `UserFactory`

especificamente esta linea:

```
'picture'=>\Faker\Provider\Image::image(storage_patch().'/app/public/users',200,200,'people',false),
```

Lo que me tiene pensando es que tengo otra tabla que tambien necesita imagenes y no me genera error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es un error tipográfico.

Cambia esta línea:

```php
'picture'=> \Faker\Provider\Image::image(storage_patch().'/app/public/users', /** */),
```

por esta otra:

```php
'picture'=> \Faker\Provider\Image::image(storage_path().'/app/public/users', /** */),
```

---

El nombre del helper es `storage_path()`, no `storage_patch()`.

> ### `storage_path()`
>
> La función `storage_path` devuelve la ruta totalmente cualificada al
>   directorio `storage`. También puede utilizar la función `storage_path`
>   para generar una ruta totalmente cualificada a un archivo determinado
>   dentro del directorio storage:
>
> ```php
> $path = storage_path();
>
> $path = storage_path('app/file.txt');
> ```